# Как отобразить данные из карты в templates

Tags: golang

Как отобразить данные из карты (ключ: значение) в html templates. Данный код отображает только значения из карты

```
var name_city string
var id string

d := make(map[string]string)

for rows.Next() {

    rows.Scan(&id, &name_city)

    d[id] = name_city
    
}


tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", d)
```

Код из шаблона

```
{{range .}}
<li><a href="test/{{.}}">{{.}}</a></li>
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{range $key, $value := .}}
{{$key}} {{$value}} <br>
{{end}}
```